# Why only random-access-iterator implements operator+ in C++?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I'd like get far next value for STL `list` iterator but it doesn't implement `operator+`, `vector` has it though. Why and how can I get the value where I want?

I think I can do that if I call `operator++` several times, but isn't that a little bit dirty?

What I want to do is the following:

```
list<int> l;
...omitted...
list<int>::iterator itr = l.begin() + 3; // but, list iterator does not have
                                         // operator+
```

What is the best solution for what I want?

Comment: (Almost) unrelated: you need to make sure that it's possible to reach this position, otherwise you'll invoke undefined behavior. Though from `list<T>::begin()` it's easy, in a more generic case, the only way to know (for non RandomAccessIterator) the distance with `list<T>::end()` is is to invoke `std::distance`... O(N) too.

Comment: Two excellent answers on this thread.  +1 to the community!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can also use [`std::next`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next) (and prev) or the equivalents provided by Boost if you don't have access to C++11.

```
list<int>::iterator itr = std::next(l.begin(), 3);
```

Rationale: `std::advance` is awkward to use (it works by side-effect, not by returning a copy).

Comment: That's good to know.  I always wondered why `std::advance` worked by side-effect instead of functionally.

Comment: @RSam: I have always assumed it is because `std::advance` is meant to mimic ++itr or operator+=, as appropriate.  Iterator algorithms are generally written in those terms, so wrapping them makes the most sense.

Comment: If you want a copy you have to create one yourself. This is common case in c++.

Answer (score 37):

You want to use [std::advance](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance):

```
list<int>::iterator itr = l.begin();
std::advance(itr, 3);
```

`advance` will use `operator+` and complete in constant time if the iterator is random access while it will loop on `operator++` and complete in linear time if the iterator is not random access.

The reason for this is to give you control over complexity requirements. If you care about the complexity of your operation you use `operator+` and get constant time but this only compiles with random access iterators. If you don't care about the complexity you use `std::advance` which will always work but the complexity will vary based on the iterator.